# Exporting NetCDF file as GeoTiFF

Tags: pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I am trying to automate the export of NetCDF files into GeoTIFF. However the export could not give me the same result that I do it manually. I am quite new so wasn't sure which part went wrong.
This is the information of export I wanted:

```
Information from provider
Name    test_compare
Path    D:\WAIG\Progs\qgis_nc\compare_output\test_compare.tif
CRS EPSG:32649 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 49N - Projected
Extent  152123.7194000000017695,85660.8351999999722466 : 847876.2806000001728535,611607.4255000000121072
Unit    meters
Width   70
Height  53
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description D:\WAIG\Progs\qgis_nc\compare_output\test_compare.tif
Compression 
Band 1  
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=100984.875
STATISTICS_MEAN=100244.48617124
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=91913.625
STATISTICS_STDDEV=1502.4594772555
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
More information    
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Dimensions  X: 70 Y: 53 Bands: 1
Origin  152124,611607
Pixel Size  9939.322302857144678,-9923.520571698114509
```

Where the result I get from the script is:

```
Information from provider
Name    testing_written
Path    D:\WAIG\Progs\qgis_nc\test_output\testing_written.tif
CRS EPSG:32649 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 49N - Projected
Extent  152123.7194000000017695,85660.8351999999722466 : 847876.2806000001728535,611607.4255000000121072
Unit    meters
Width   70
Height  53
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description D:\WAIG\Progs\qgis_nc\test_output\testing_written.tif
Compression 
Band 1  
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=0
More information    
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Dimensions  X: 70 Y: 53 Bands: 1
Origin  152124,611607
Pixel Size  9939.322302857144678,-9923.520571698114509
```

I am not sure how to export the bands together as well, I have read the documentation but at my stage its quite hard to understand... But anyway here's the code:

```
from qgis.core import *

#use path as input
uri='NETCDF:"D:\WAIG\Progs\ERA5_download\Downloaded_nc_file\sample_input/era5_surface_pressure_2009-12-27_0000.nc":sp'

#create layer to store nc file
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer (uri,'layer20091227_0000')
rlayer.setCrs ( QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(rlayer.dataProvider().clone())

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('D:\\WAIG\\Progs\\qgis_nc\\test_output/'+'testing_written.tif')
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, 70, -1, QgsRectangle(152123.7194000000017695,85660.8351999999722466,847876.2806000001728535,611607.4255000000121072),  QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32649))
```